# How to manually set group.id and commit kafka offsets in spark structured streaming?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming, spark-kafka-integration

I was going through the Spark structured streaming - Kafka integration guide [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html).

It is told at this link that

> enable.auto.commit: Kafka source doesn’t commit any offset.

So how do I manually commit offsets once my spark application has successfully processed each record?

Answer (score 14):

tl;dr

It is not possible to commit any messages to Kafka. Starting with Spark version 3.x you can define the name of the Kafka consumer group, however, this still does not allow you to commit any messages.

---

## Since Spark 3.0.0

According to the [Structured Kafka Integration Guide](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html) you can provide the ConsumerGroup as an option `kafka.group.id`:

```scala
val df = spark
  .readStream
  .format("kafka")
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "host1:port1,host2:port2")
  .option("subscribe", "topic1")
  .option("kafka.group.id", "myConsumerGroup")
  .load()
```

However, Spark still will **not commit any offsets back** so you will not be able to "manually" commit offsets to Kafka. This feature is meant to deal with Kafka's latest feature [Authorization using Role-Based Access Control](https://docs.confluent.io/current/security/rbac/index.html) for which your ConsumerGroup usually needs to follow naming conventions.

A full example of a Spark 3.x application is discussed and solved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64003405/how-to-use-kafka-group-id-in-spark-3-0-to-avoid-always-start-the-offset-for-late/64003569#64003569).

## Until Spark 2.4.x

The Spark [Structured Streaming + Kafka integration Guide](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html) clearly states how it manages Kafka offsets. Spark will **not commit any messages back to Kafka** as it is relying on internal offset management for fault-tolerance.

The most important Kafka configurations for managing offsets are:

- **group.id:** Kafka source will create a unique group id for each query automatically. According to the [code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.4.0/external/kafka-0-10-sql/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/kafka010/KafkaSourceProvider.scala#L124) the group.id will be set to

```scala
val uniqueGroupId = s"spark-kafka-source-${UUID.randomUUID}-${metadataPath.hashCode}"
```

- **auto.offset.reset:** Set the source option startingOffsets to specify where to start instead.
  *Structured Streaming manages which offsets are consumed internally, rather than rely on the kafka Consumer to do it.*
- **enable.auto.commit:** Kafka source doesn’t commit any offset.

Therefore, in Structured Streaming it is currently not possible to define your custom group.id for Kafka Consumer and Structured Streaming is managing the offsets internally and not committing back to Kafka (also not automatically).

### 2.4.x in Action

Let's say you have a simple Spark Structured Streaming application that reads and writes to Kafka, like this:

```scala
// create SparkSession
val spark = SparkSession.builder()
  .appName("ListenerTester")
  .master("local[*]")
  .getOrCreate()

// read from Kafka topic
val df = spark.readStream
  .format("kafka")
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
  .option("subscribe", "testingKafkaProducer")
  .option("failOnDataLoss", "false")
  .load()

// write to Kafka topic and set checkpoint directory for this stream
df.selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING)", "CAST(value AS STRING)")
  .writeStream
  .format("kafka")
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
  .option("topic", "testingKafkaProducerOut")
  .option("checkpointLocation", "/home/.../sparkCheckpoint/")
  .start()
```

#### Offset Management by Spark

Once this application is submitted and data is being processed, the corresponding offset can be found in the checkpoint directory:

myCheckpointDir/offsets/

```sh
{"testingKafkaProducer":{"0":1}}
```

Here the entry in the checkpoint file confirms that the next offset of partition `0` to be consumed is `1`. It implies that the application already processes offset `0` from partition `0` of the topic named `testingKafkaProducer`.

More on the fault-tolerance-semantics are given in the Spark [Documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#fault-tolerance-semantics).

#### Offset Management by Kafka

However, as stated in the documentation, the offset is **not** committed back to Kafka.
This can be checked by executing the `kafka-consumer-groups.sh` of the Kafka installation.

> ./kafka/current/bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --describe --group "spark-kafka-source-92ea6f85-[...]-driver-0"

```sh
TOPIC                PARTITION  CURRENT-OFFSET  LOG-END-OFFSET  LAG  CONSUMER-ID      HOST         CLIENT-ID
testingKafkaProducer 0          -               1               -    consumer-1-[...] /127.0.0.1   consumer-1
```

The current offset for this application is unknown to *Kafka* as it has never been committed.

### Possible Workaround

> Please carefully read the comments below from Spark committer @JungtaekLim about the workaround: "Spark's fault tolerance guarantee is based on the fact Spark has a full control of offset management, and they're voiding the guarantee if they're trying to modify it. (e.g. If they change to commit offset to Kafka, then there's no batch information and if Spark needs to move back to the specific batch "behind" guarantee is no longer valid.)"

What I have seen doing some research on the web is that you could commit offsets in the callback function of the `onQueryProgress` method in a customized `StreamingQueryListener` of Spark. That way, you could have a consumer group that keeps track of the current progress. However, its progress is *not* necessarily aligned with the actual consumer group.

Here are some links you may find helpful:

- [Code Example for Listener](https://gist.github.com/timvw/ddb5dfd470eb06786209e218fce5e190)
- [Discussion on SO around offset management](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46153105/how-to-get-kafka-offsets-for-structured-query-for-manual-and-reliable-offset-man?rq=1)
- [General description on the StreamingQueryListener](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/spark-structured-streaming/spark-sql-streaming-StreamingQueryListener.html)

Comment: Thanks for referring my PR and repository, but I have to correct one thing - there's NO way to commit offset manually. That's by intention to give Spark full control of offset management, instead of relying on Kafka. My PR & repository is to commit offset on "different" group ID, so that end users are able to leverage such information to integrate with Kafka ecosystem UI/admin tool.

Comment: Hi @JungtaekLim, thank you for making this clear. I re-read my answer and your statement already seems to be reflected with my sentence "Structured Streaming is managing the offsets internally and not committing back to Kafka (also not automatically)." Let me know, if you still think this is confusing or mis-leading.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I have to say again there's NO possible approach and end users shouldn't try to do it. The answer should be simply NO. Spark's fault tolerance guarantee is based on the fact Spark has a full control of offset management, and they're voiding the guarantee if they're trying to modify it. (e.g. If they change to commit offset to Kafka, then there's no batch information and if Spark needs to move back to the specific batch "behind" guarantee is no longer valid.)

Comment: Thank you again @JungtaekLim for taking the time to read an "old" answer and provide some very helpful insights. I fully agree with your arguments and tried to point it out in my answer.

Comment: My pleasure. Actually I somehow visited this because someone got mislead by this answer and consider my project as a solution on actual problem (regarding offset issue on Kafka data source), whereas it isn't and it can't be.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow how Confluent RBAC documentation affects whether Spark manages offsets or Kafka does