# Spark Offset Management in Kafka

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming, spark-kafka-integration

I am using Spark Structured Streaming (Version 2.3.2). I need to read from Kafka Cluster and write into Kerberized Kafka.
Here I want to use Kafka as offset checkpointing after the record is written into Kerberized Kafka.

Questions:

1. Can we use Kafka for checkpointing to manage offset or do we need to use only HDFS/S3 only?

Please help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to manually set group.id and commit kafka offsets in spark structured streaming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50844449/how-to-manually-set-group-id-and-commit-kafka-offsets-in-spark-structured-stream)

Comment: I want to commit the offset in source Kafka after the write is done on the sink kafka, till then i don't want to commit the offset.

Comment: You need to work with the framework, not against it. As @mike states as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can we use Kafka for checkpointing to manage offset

No, you cannot commit offsets back to your source Kafka topic. This is described in detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50844449/how-to-manually-set-group-id-and-commit-kafka-offsets-in-spark-structured-stream) and of course in the official [Spark Structured Streaming + Kafka Integration Guide](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html).

> or do we need to use only HDFS/S3 only?

Yes, this has to be something like HDFS or S3. This is explained in section [Recovering from Failures with Checkpointing](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#recovering-from-failures-with-checkpointing) of the StructuredStreaming Programming Guide: "This checkpoint location has to be a path **in an HDFS compatible file system**, and can be set as an option in the DataStreamWriter when starting a query."