# Structured Streaming startingOffest and Checkpoint

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming, spark-kafka-integration

I am confused about `startingOffsets` in structured streaming.
In the official docs [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html), it says query type

1. *Streaming* - is this continuous streaming?
2. *Batch* - is this for query with forEachBatch or triggers? (latest is not allowed)

My workflow also has `checkpoints` enabled. How does this work together with `startingOffsets`?
If my workflow crashes and I have `startingOffsets` as `latest`, does spark check kafka offset or the spark checkpoint offset or both?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Streaming* by default means "micro-batch" in Spark. Dependent on the trigger you set, it will check the source for new data on the given frequency. You can use it by

```scala
val df = spark
  .readStream
  .format("kafka")
  .[...]
```

For Kafka there is also the experimental **continuous** trigger that allows processing of the data with quite a low latency. See the section [Continuous Processing](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#continuous-processing) in the documentation.

*Batch* on the other hand works like reading a text file (such as csv) that you do once. You can do this by using

```scala
val df = spark
  .read
  .format("kafka")
  .[...]
```

Note the difference in `readStream` for streaming and `read` for batch processing. In batch mode the `startingOffset` can only be set to `earliest` and even if you use checkpointing it will always start from earliest offset in case of a planned or unplanned restart.

Checkpointing in Structured Streaming needs to be set in the `writeStream` part and needs to be unique for every single query (in case you are running multiple streaming queries from the same source). If you have that checkpoint location set up and you restart your application Spark will only look into those checkpoint files. Only when the query gets started for the very first time it checks the `startingOffset` option.

Remember that Structured Streaming *never* commits any offsets back to Kafka. It only relies on its  checkpoint files. See my other answer on [How to manually set group.id and commit kafka offsets in spark structured streaming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50844449/how-to-manually-set-group-id-and-commit-kafka-offsets-in-spark-structured-stream/60787959#60787959).

In case you plan to run your application, say, once a day it is therefore best to use `readStream` with checkpointing enabled and the trigger `writeStream.trigger(Trigger.Once)`. A good explanation for this approach is given in a Databricks blog on [Running Streaming Jobs Once a Day For 10x Cost Savings](https://databricks.com/blog/2017/05/22/running-streaming-jobs-day-10x-cost-savings.html).