# Python ReadStream from kafka by earliest mode from offset manually commited

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

I need help in my pyspark streaming code.
In Python/spark streaming, i have code with readStream from Kafka by earliest mode.
every day a stream of data arrives.
I want to run my stream so that it fetches every day in earliest mode from the last committed offset.

- How to manually retrieve (via pyspark code) the last committed offset?
- How to commit the offset.

  ```
  df = spark.readStream.format("kafka")\
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", serveurs)\
  .option("subscribe", topic_name) \
  .option("startingOffsets", "earliest")\
  .option("kafka.group.id" , "consumer-id")\
  .option("kafka.security.protocol", "SSL")\
  .option("kafka.ssl.truststore.location",  truststore_location ) \
  .option("kafka.ssl.truststore.type", "JKS") \
  .option("kafka.ssl.truststore.password", truststore_pwd) \
  .option("kafka.ssl.keystore.location", keystore_location ) \
  .option("kafka.ssl.keystore.type", "JKS") \
  .option("kafka.ssl.keystore.password", keystore_pwd) \
  .option("enable.auto.commit", "TRUE") \
  .load()\
  .selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING)", "CAST(value AS STRING)")

    query = df\
    .select("value")\
    .writeStream\
    .queryName("event")\
    .outputMode("append")\
    .format("parquet")\
    .option("path", HDFS_LOCATION + '/' + str(date.today()))\
    .option("checkpointLocation", HDFS_LOCATION + '/' + str(date.today()))\
    .trigger(processingTime='30 seconds')\
    .option("truncate", False)\
    .start()\
    .awaitTermination()
  ```

Thank's a lot.

Comment: You cannot enable auto commits with Spark. Add checkpointLocation to your readStream. Then offsets should be stored there

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50844449/how-to-manually-set-group-id-and-commit-kafka-offsets-in-spark-structured-stream