# significance of kafka consumer group in spark structured streaming

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

planning to build spark structured streaming application, which reads json data from Kafka topic, parses the data and writes to any of the storage.

```
val df = spark
  .readStream
  .format("kafka")
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "host1:port1,host2:port2")
  .option("subscribe", "topic1")
  .option("kafka.group.id", "myConsumerGroup")
  .load()
```

As per the spark doc, Consumer group id is internally generated by the Apache Spark ie. By default, each query generates a unique group id for reading data or we can specify using kafka.group.id. I understand that Within a consumer group, at any time a kafka partition can only be consumed by a single consumer. If all we have to do is read, parse and write, what is the significance of kafka.group.id, do we need to explicitly set this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64003405/how-to-use-kafka-group-id-and-checkpoints-in-spark-3-0-structured-streaming-to-c

Comment: went through this earlier before posting, could not find what I was looking for. I have added a comment to your answer below.

Comment: Actually. Given hoe Spark works you need not set at all unless you want 2 apps to consum same data independently.

Comment: if 2 apps want to consume data independently, then also we dont want to set this right? because spark by default assigns a unique value for each app/query, so they will have different id's so that they can read complete data independently.

Comment: You can still set it. Just use different strings for the group ids

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would avoid using it. From the manuals, there is a specific use-case:

> The Kafka group id to use in Kafka consumer while reading from Kafka.
> **Use this with caution.** By default, each query generates a unique group
> id for reading data. This ensures that each Kafka source has its own
> consumer group that does not face interference from any other
> consumer, and therefore can read all of the partitions of its
> subscribed topics. In some scenarios (for example, Kafka group-based
> authorization), **you may want to use a specific authorized group id to
> read data**. You can optionally set the group id. However, do this with
> extreme caution as it can cause unexpected behavior. Concurrently
> running queries (both, batch and streaming) or sources with the same
> group id are likely interfere with each other causing each query to
> read only part of the data. This may also occur when queries are
> started/restarted in quick succession. To minimize such issues, set
> the Kafka consumer session timeout (by setting option
> "kafka.session.timeout.ms") to be very small. When this is set, option
> "groupIdPrefix" will be ignored.

I have been filling data lakes for a while now, and on the last project we just had multiple queries - 1 per App, (1 App for RAW- ingestion, 1 App for REF- ingestion, 1 App for BUS- Data Zone processing and ingestion), and it worked fine. With the 3.x upgrade we looked at what you are asking, but left it as is.

Spark Structured Streaming 'sits on top' and allocates resources as per what you have defined, so performance  should be fine for most aspects, you can add more.

Comment: got it. So last question on this, when 2 different spark structured streaming codes read from same kafka queue on same spark cluster, they are assigned unique group id, so wont interfere with each other, should be able to read complete data from kafka. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes that is correct. @steve

Comment: My interpretation of the "caution" docs is no different than other Kafka consumer apps. Don't re-use a group that some other app is using, otherwise you'll cause that app to rebalance and data would be consumed from two different apps, causing both to read a subset of the partitions they expect. Otherwise, the authorization example is a good example where policies must be granted to static group names.

Comment: Yes. But not many know much about kafka. @OneCricketeer

Answer (score 2):

> do we need to explicitly set this?

No. As you've discovered, Spark will automatically create one. You could also give a group prefix rather than a static string.

> If all we have to do is read, parse and write, what is the significance

This isn't really a Spark question. Kafka consumers use consumer groups for scalability and preventing duplicate reads

You *could* use the value to store offsets back in Kafka manually, but otherwise checkpoint files can give better processing guarantees than Kafka's at least once behavior.

Comment: I can understand - preventing duplicate reads, but how it helps in scalability. Lets say we have single spark structured streaming code/app that reads from Kafka. As long as we have right balance of kafka partition and spark parallelism(cores), we are good.  so why do we need consumer group? Is my understanding not right?

Comment: Partitions+Threads/cores are for scalability, yes. I was more referring to the fencing mechanism of the groups on each partition